# Woocommerce product archive page - custom layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here's my staging site with the layout I'm trying to achive with about 35 products.

My question: I understand how to create a product loop (WOO), but I'm wondering if an experienced WP dev can point me in the right direction. Would you create a CUSTOM if loop so that after an item is output with the image on the left and the description on the right, the next item to follow will have the desc on the left and the image on the right?

Would you create a custom post type for this? Or use Woocommerce?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You're saying you want to show WC products on some other page other than default shop page. I would suggest that use same WC product with your desire template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, i would do a Custom Post Type with

- metas (Prices, Subtitle, ...)
- taxonomies

Comment: Is there an easy way to add import / export functionality to it though like what I would get by going with Woocommerce?

Comment: Check with wpallimport. You can import/export csv

Comment: @Sco If I'm not wrong you're suggesting copy the same records into database with different POST TYPE. If so I recommend use WC default. WC products saved as CPT 'products'. No need to unnecessary overhead on Database.

Comment: Yes I agree with you ... If WC is installed but without WC a small script (CTP + Taxo + Metas) does the job.

I'm not a fan of using WC for 35 products

Comment: Thanks for the help!